# Shimmer device X Y Z Axis

Tags: axis, calibration

I am conducting an experiment regarding the detection of movement using a shimmer device (X, Y, Z axis).

If the person is lying on the ground, is this the X, Y or Z axis?

Comment: This is an odd question.  The ground is a plane.  Therefore, if it's axis-aligned, it spans two axes.  Did you mean 'which axis is "up"'?  Don't you get to choose your axis system?

Comment: the experiment is for a sleep detection system in order to identify sleep walking